# RobotFramework: Correct tabbing for multiple keywords in if statements

Tags: robotframework

See below - im trying to figure out whether this will work. The code will take ages to get to when running so just wanted to see if anyone can spot any issue. As per the tabbing, the 4 bottom keywords should be run if the condition is satisfied

```
Run keyword if  '${user_check}' == 'yes'
...  Run Keywords
     ...  Validate User Record
          ...  ${created_at}
          ...  ${create_or_update_in_db}
          Validate User Audits Record
          Validate User Sponsor Assignments Record
          Validate User Sponsor Assignment Audits Record
```

Comment: Why not put all the validating keywords in a new keyword `Validate User Records`?

Comment: Yeah will try that thanks

Answer (score 2):

The syntax of `Run Keyword If` by itself is correct, it expects a single keyword to run if the condition holds true.

The `Run Keywords` on the other hand needs a special delimiter to know what is the difference between a keyword, and its arguments - [the word "AND"](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Run%20Keywords), capital case.

So in your case, it should be

```
Run keyword if  '${user_check}' == 'yes'
...  Run Keywords
     ...  Validate User Record  ${created_at}  ${create_or_update_in_db}   AND
     ...  Validate User Audits Record                 AND
     ...  Validate User Sponsor Assignments Record    AND
     ...  Validate User Sponsor Assignment Audits Record
```

And the triple dots (`...`) is just used when you want to split a single line of arguments (like any keyword in RF requires them) into multiple lines.